# Why my ViewPager maybe a blank page？？？

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I thought ViewPager dynamic display pictures, pictures address array by activity coming in, but the image is larger than 3, sliding to the left and right sliding is no problem, but when the picture a number less than or equal to 3, slider to the right (back sliding) there will be a blank page, what in the end is what the reason?

```
  private void initView(){
            dateAfterSplit=mScreen.split(",");
            tips = new ImageView[dateAfterSplit.length];
            for(int i=0; i<tips.length; i++){
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(10,10));
                tips[i] = imageView;
                if(i == 0){
                    tips[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page_indicator_focused);
                }else {
                    tips[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.page_indicator_unfocused);
                }
                mGroup.addView(imageView);
            }
            mImageViews=new ImageView[dateAfterSplit.length];
            for(int i=0; i<mImageViews.length; i++){
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                mImageViews[i] = imageView;
                mImageLoader.displayImage(imageView, dateAfterSplit[i],
                        R.drawable.app_icon, mIsLoaderAlbumFromCache);
            }
            mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mPictureId);}

Left and right infinite loop    
  public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            return arg0 == arg1;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
           ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) mImageViews[position % mImageViews.length]);
            Log.i("APP", "destroyItem"+position);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {

            try{  
                if(mImageViews[position % mImageViews.length].getParent()==null){
                    ((ViewPager)container).addView(mImageViews[position % mImageViews.length]);
                }
                else {
                    ((ViewGroup)mImageViews[position % mImageViews.length].getParent()).removeView(mImageViews[position % mImageViews.length]);
                    ((ViewPager) container).addView(mImageViews[position % mImageViews.length] , 0); 
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {   
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
            Log.i("APP", "instantiateItem"+position);
            return mImageViews[position % mImageViews.length];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add This to PagerAdapter this Could Solve Your Problem

> public int getItemPosition (Object object) { return POSITION_NONE; }

Comment: I don't think this can resolve my question,can you see it again?